# How can I make the bowser library globally available on a web page?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, global, umd

I'm working on a SPA where under some condition I have to log some browser and operating system data. So I loaded the script for the `bowser` library - when the condition is met - but unfortunately I can't use this in any way ... :(

On their official demo page - https://bowser-js.github.io/bowser-online/ - there is a global `window.bowser` object which can be directly used. But this simply doesn't happen when I just load the JS file on a web page.

Any idea what should I do? Or probably a better approach than mine?

---

I tried to load the library in several ways:

1. With jQuery's getScript method:

```
    $.getScript('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bowser@latest/es5.js');
```

2. With native JS:

```
    var bowserScript = document.createElement('script');
    bowserScript.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bowser@latest/es5.js';
    document.body.appendChild(bowserScript);
```

In both cases I see the network request in the browser and don't see errors in the browser's console.

I tried the same on different page on the website - and then all worked fine - I have the global `window.bowser` variable ... but not on my page ... :O

So - any idea what `thing` on this page could be the reason for the bowser library to not work there? ...

Comment: Loading the library won't set the global for you, but it is trivial to set it.

Comment: @tadman - I'd love to see how it can be done. Can you please show me?

Comment: Afaik, it's a module, so you'll need your own module that loads it and adds it to `window`.

Comment: Aaah ... I wanted to make it globally available directly, without the need to bundle one more file just to do this ... :(

Comment: `window.x = y` is not going to require a module.

Comment: @tadman - I agree, but what should be in place of `y`? ...

Comment: **The module you want to make global**.

Comment: But if I have a dead simple web page where I'm loading their JS file - nothing will be exposed to be used globally ... ... Probably I'm not describing the issue clearly enough ...

Comment: You will need to explain in more detail, surely.

Comment: Something like `window.bowser = require('bowser');`

Comment: FYI: Making globals is usually considered a bad practice as you run the risk of overwriting existing global properties. You should make a namespace and set up the alias in that namespace.

Comment: I fetched the below script and evaluated the response, and could then access "window.bowser".

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bowser@latest/es5.js

Comment: Make sure you waited for the scripts to load before executing any of your code by referring to this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

, or use the script onload event.

Comment: How are you loading bowser? Update your question to show the code.

Comment: For me, `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bowser/2.11.0/bundled.js"></script>` works, adds it as `window.bowser`, and allows my scripts access it as simply `bowser`.

Comment: @Ouroborus - I updated the question with some code on how I load the library on the page. It works on other pages but not on mine ... no idea what could prevent this on that particular page though ...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Showing how you load the library without showing how that relates to how you then use it isn’t really enough to go on.